# Is there a way to get various REGEXP

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

```
SELECT COUNT(nomes) AS Number of machines that use certain name FROM pos_systems
WHERE active=1
AND nomes IS NOT NULL
AND nomes <>''
AND nomes REGEXP 'akira'
```

What I want is to know if there's a way to display multiples REGEXP in the same query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use the multiple `REGEXP` in same query as below

```
AND nomes REGEXP 'akira|secondvalue|thirdvalue'
```

[Here is more info.](http://www.sqlines.com/mysql/regexp_rlike)